# Capturing Image in Iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a blank screen on which i click camera button and take photo and than that photo appears on my blank screen as a `UIVIew` and i'm adding multiple images from Camera to blank screen. The problem is sometimes i can add multiple images on blank screen but sometimes when i capture image and than all images on blank screen disappear and just shows the current image.

[image]

```
- (IBAction)openCameraOnAddButton:(id)sender {
//NSLog(@"openCameraOnAddButton");
[AddImagesToCanvasView setHidden:YES];
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];  
picker.delegate = self; 
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;  
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

}

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
UIImage *image = [[info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"] retain];


UIView *holderView;
if(image.size.width > image.size.height || image.size.width == image.size.height)
{
    holderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 180, 160)];
}
else{
    holderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 160, 240)];
}
UIImageView *imageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:[holderView frame]];
[imageview setImage:image];
NSLog(@"Tag By Default %d",(arc4random()%100)+10);
[holderView setTag:(int)objectDelegate.tagForHolderView];
[imageview setTag:((int)objectDelegate.tagForHolderView)+1];
[holderView addSubview:imageview];


UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchRecognizer = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(scale:)];
[pinchRecognizer setDelegate:self];
[holderView addGestureRecognizer:pinchRecognizer];

 UIRotationGestureRecognizer *rotationRecognizer = [[UIRotationGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rotate:)];
 [rotationRecognizer setDelegate:self];
 [holderView addGestureRecognizer:rotationRecognizer];

UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(move:)];
[panRecognizer setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1];
[panRecognizer setMaximumNumberOfTouches:1];
[panRecognizer setDelegate:self];
[holderView addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];

UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapped:)];
[tapRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
[tapRecognizer setDelegate:self];
[holderView addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer]; 


 UILongPressGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(gestureHandler:)];
 [holderView addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];

[holderView.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]];
[holderView.layer setBorderWidth: 3.0];
[self.view addSubview:holderView];
objectDelegate.tagForHolderView+=2;

}
```

Comment: paste code of image capture..

Comment: because you are allocating memory to holderView all time when your didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo is calling...so just alloc your holderView in viewDidLoad..

Comment: Thanks. i have removes allocation of holderview from didFinishPcikingMediInfo to header file. but its behaving same

Comment: where are you allocing holderView... and one thing, what is the size of capture image..?

Comment: i m allocating holderView in .h file . image size is normal. like if you are capturing image from camera. thats the size

Comment: can you please tell me how to alloc in .h file.... :)

Comment: i m sorry . i mean that i have define it in header.. not allocating :)

Comment: ok if i am allocating in viewDIdload but how will i change the the size of frame CGRectMake(0, 0, 180, 160)];?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20308/discussion-between-zohaib-and-rajneesh071)

Comment: why are you not implementing you code like this tutorial..this is nice and easy tutorila....

Comment: i have implement it but its also have the same issue. the app crashed after 10 to 15 images

Comment: Hey problem is with your objectDelegate.tagForHolderView , just comment the line where you are setting tag in the code, and then run

Comment: but i have sent you url of that tutorial i have implement . in that tutorial that line is not there. but still on device after 4 to 5 images all images are removed

Comment: No man ,  that url code working fine at my end...i added 20+ images but did not got any crash..

Comment: are you trying it on real device or simulator. in simulator my code is also working fine, but in real device. 3gs n 4s. its not working.

Comment: try it in real device . it will not work properly

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but as you are doing all the operation **UIImagePickerCotroller's** delegate methods sometimes it may not work.

I faced same problem while storing the image in document directory & to resolve this i had created new Thread in **didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo** method & moved entire code in that method. Then after it works fine for me. Try to do that.

Comment: ok let me try this than i will let you know if it works or not